# RNOneSignal.configure is not a function after updating OneSignal to the latest version

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, onesignal

I updated React native OneSignal from 3.2.12 version to 3.3.2 version, after that I started getting an error during app launch.

Here is an error:

> RNOneSignal.configure is not a function

"

Here is my code:

```
import OneSignal from 'react-native-onesignal';

initialize() {
        OneSignal.init(config.oneSignalAppId, {kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt : false});
        OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(0);

        OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
        OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
        OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);

        OneSignal.configure();
    }
```

How to fix this problem?

UPDATE: I found out that OneSignal code that the `configure` method has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed `OneSignal.configure();` from my code, since this method was deprecated  and removed `configure()` from `node_modules/react-native-onesignal/index.js` and app started work normally after that!

Comment: I have removed this from my code, but I am getting the same error, and it appears in the stack when I use OneSignal.addEventListener()... any suggestions on where to look for the problem?

Comment: Correction: I still had the addEventListener for 'ids' in my code as well. Removing this worked